# colspan is not working when using nested tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a table with all its rows and details, but those details have to be hidden until I click the "parent" row, that works all right but, my detail table doesn't fit to the whole row's length.

```js
var expandirButton = document.getElementsByClassName("expandir");
for (var i = 0; i < expandirButton.length; i++) {
  expandirButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var tablaAnidada = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (tablaAnidada.classList.contains("tabla-anidada")) {
      if (tablaAnidada.style.display === "block") {
        tablaAnidada.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tablaAnidada.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}


/* Estilo para ocultar la tabla anidada */

.tabla-anidada {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tabla anidada</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Tabla anidada</h2>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Fila que se expande -->
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td colspan="3">July</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Nueva fila para la tabla anidada -->
    <tr class="expandir tabla-anidada">
      <!-- Agregue el atributo "colspan" a esta celda -->
      <td colspan="3">
        <table id="myNestedTable">
          <tr>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>USA</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paris</td>
            <td>Francia</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

It's supposed it should work because I made the test with the previous row, July, and it works. Actually, if I erase .tabla-anidada class from css, It shows the way it should be, with no hide function obviously. Seems it all happens when javascript is added. I've tryed creating different css classes for each table, addinng width style attribute at different places, etc, etc.

Comment: The detail table is in a different row. Put it in the same row as the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables don't always play nice with non-table display types.  I changed your `tablaAnidada.style.display = "block";` to `tablaAnidada.style.display = "table-row";` and I think this is probably the result you're going for.

```js
var expandirButton = document.getElementsByClassName("expandir");
for (var i = 0; i < expandirButton.length; i++) {
  expandirButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var tablaAnidada = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (tablaAnidada.classList.contains("tabla-anidada")) {
      if (tablaAnidada.style.display === "block") {
        tablaAnidada.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tablaAnidada.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}


/* Estilo para ocultar la tabla anidada */

.tabla-anidada {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tabla anidada</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Tabla anidada</h2>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Fila que se expande -->
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td colspan="3">July</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Nueva fila para la tabla anidada -->
    <tr class="expandir tabla-anidada">
      <!-- Agregue el atributo "colspan" a esta celda -->
      <td colspan="3">
        <table id="myNestedTable">
          <tr>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>USA</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paris</td>
            <td>Francia</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
var expandirButton = document.getElementsByClassName("expandir");
for (var i = 0; i < expandirButton.length; i++) {
  expandirButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var tablaAnidada = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (tablaAnidada.classList.contains("tabla-anidada")) {
      if (tablaAnidada.style.display === "table-row") {
        tablaAnidada.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tablaAnidada.style.display = "table-row";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}


/* Estilo para ocultar la tabla anidada */

.tabla-anidada {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tabla anidada</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Tabla anidada</h2>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Edad</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Fila que se expande -->
    <tr class="expandir">
      <td colspan="3">July</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Nueva fila para la tabla anidada -->
    <tr class="expandir tabla-anidada">
      <!-- Agregue el atributo "colspan" a esta celda -->
      <td colspan="3">
        <table id="myNestedTable">
          <tr>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>USA</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paris</td>
            <td>Francia</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could also consider using `tablaAnidada.classList.toggle("<a class that just has display: none in it>");` this will clean up your JS a little bit.

Comment: I just found this great reference, for those who want to learn more about tables [link] https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

Comment: do you know if this aproach will work with datatables? I mean, the detail is in a different row... thanks

Comment: I don't know, sorry - never used DataTables :(